# Invalid command for httpd -t -c

Tags: apache

This suggests debugging Apache with:

```
httpd -t -c httpd.conf
```

However, running it on my Mac with Apache version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) I get:

```
$ httpd -t -c /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of -c/-C directives:
Invalid command '/etc/apache2/httpd.conf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Looks like that should be `-f httpd.conf` rather than `-c httpd.conf`.  Check `man httpd` - the `-f` option is for specifying a config file, not `-c`.

Comment: Spot on. Yes, wonder if that was a typo or if the config settings have changed.

Comment: I suspect it was a typo, because lots of init scripts would rely on the option to override the config location and it would be a big deal to change it. Where did you see that debugging suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`-c` is used to process an apache directive before reading httpd.conf
example..

```
httpd -c "Alias /myweb/ /var/www/" -t -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

as  Michael Berkowski said it could be a typo.